# Mysql get randomly but try to get with the smallest values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a row in MySQL table named `number_of_times`,i sent this query to SQL `SELECT * FROM Vocab ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 3` and it returns 3 random datas,how can i select 3 random numbers,but from the ones where the `number_of_times` row is the smallest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose the smallest values.  Just use `number_of_times` as the first key in the `order by`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Vocab
ORDER BY number_of_times asc, Rand()
LIMIT 3;
```

Note:  If you only want values with the smallest `number_of_times` -- even if there are not 3 of them -- then this may be faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM Vocab
WHERE number_of_times = (SELECT MIN(number_of_times) from Vocab)
ORDER BY Rand()
LIMIT 3;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `Vocab(number_of_times)`.